# NSXML replacing "<" with "%lt;"

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa, nsxml

I see there are other questions related to this, but none using NSXML.

So, I'm constructing an XML document from scratch using NSXML and when I create a NSXMLNode with a string value, all the "<" characters in that string are replaced with "& lt;" when I output the node, or save it to a file.

Example:

```
 NSXMLNode *description = [NSXMLNode elementWithName:@"description"
                               stringValue:@"<![CDATA[Some Description</a>]]>"];
```

Then when I do

```
 NSLog(@"description: %@", description);
```

I get the node with all the '<' characters replaced with "& lt;". However when I do

```
 NSLog(@"description string value: %@", [description stringValue]);
```

I get the correct string output. This XML document is going to be saved as a KML file for google earth, and google earth gives me an error when it finds the "& lt;" token. Any idea how to make NSXML just output the '<'? I'm using OSX 10.6 and XCode 3.2 btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a special options flag for indicating CDATA that will help here. The trick is to let cocoa write the `<![CDATA[` and `]]` bookends for you:

```
NSXMLNode *cdata = [[[NSXMLNode alloc] initWithKind:NSXMLTextKind
                                            options:NSXMLNodeIsCDATA] autorelease];
[cdata setStringValue:@"Some CDATA Description"];

NSXMLElement *description = [NSXMLNode elementWithName:@"description"];
[description addChild:cdata];

NSLog(@"description: %@", description);

// yields: <description><![CDATA[Some CDATA Description]]></description>
```

To obtain a string with the angle brackets intact:

```
NSString *output = [description XMLString];
```