# XML parsing - iPhone

Tags: iphone, parsing, xml-parsing, nsxml

Hello I am new to iPhone development.
I have created one application that consume data from web service. And it works fine but I have a problem with parsing.

The xml data that I get from the web service is:

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-tart</a>]:
Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at D:\xampp\htdocs\system    
\application\controllers\isignin.php:4)</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/session.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 146</p>

</div><div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p> 
<p>Message:  session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]:      Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at D:\xampp\htdocs\6d\system    \application\controllers\isignin.php:4)</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/session.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 146</p>

</div><div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\xampp\htdocs\6d\system\application\controllers\isignin.php:4)</p>
<p>Filename: codeigniter/Common.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 360</p>

</div><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml><item>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;&lt;newblock&gt;&lt;name&gt;abcde
&lt;/name&gt;&lt;password&gt;12345678&lt;/password&gt;&lt;/newblock&gt;</item></xml>
```

This is what I call from connectionDidFinishLoading method:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {
      NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);


  if (xmlParser)
   {
    [xmlParser release];
  }    
   xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: webData];
   [xmlParser setDelegate: self];
   [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];
   [xmlParser parse];



   [connection release];
   [webData release];
}
```

The following are the parsing methods used:

```
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser 
 didStartElement:(NSString *) elementName 
   namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI 
 qualifiedName:(NSString *) qName
 attributes:(NSDictionary *) attributeDict {

 if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"GetWeatherResult"])
{
  if (!soapResults)
{
 soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
}
elementFound = YES;
}
  }

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
if (elementFound)
{
    [soapResults appendString: string];
}
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
 didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
  {
  if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"GetWeatherResult"])
  {
    //---displays the country---
    NSLog(soapResults);        
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
     initWithTitle:@"Current Temperature!"                           
     message:soapResults 
     delegate:self  
     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
     otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    [soapResults setString:@""];
    elementFound = FALSE; 
}
}
```

My query is :
I want to extract the **"name" tag** with value **"abcde"** from the received XML data.
But when I search for **"name"** with value **"abcde"** in the above xml data received, parser can't find it because of **&qt, &lt** etc.

1) How to fix my NSMutableData to have normal values (<, > etc.)? Any inbuilt functions of   NSMutableData to replace  **&lt, &gt** with **<, >**?
Or
2) Is there any thing missing (or doing wrong) while generating the xml data at the server side or   Am I missing anything while parsing at the client side (on iPhone)
Or
3) Any other solution to fix the above problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try :-

```
 [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt" withString:@"<"];
```

Comment: Thanks. I have already tried this but I can't pass string to the parser. I mean NSStrin object can't be passed. IT gives error for that. We have to pass NSData or NSMutableData object only to the parser.

Comment: what i interpret from ur question is that the above is the xml data which u get and which ur parsing ...so I obviously understand that U cannot pass string to parser and is passing NSData to parser .. but on parsing , xml will give the strings and then U can use the above function given by me ... and if I am wrong anywhere in my interpretation of ur question .. then I apologise and take my answer back... but then I have found a link for u  .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813503/nsxml-replacing-with-lt

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you use TBXML library, It's a very small and has very good performance. It also quite easy to grasp , at least easier than NSXMLParser, IMHO.

1. There is no build in function to replace &lt, &gt in Objective C. So you might want to wrap that string in  on the server.